# Draw Lines in octave

Tags: plot, octave, lines

Is possible to draw lines in octave with plot or plot3?

I mean, to define a matrix with points and plot them in pairs automatically.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's very easy to draw lines in Octave.  It is, by the way, the same as in Matlab.

When you say that you have a "matrix with points" I assume you mean a n x 2 matrix.  If the matrix is called "points" then you would simply do "plot(points(:,1), points(:,2), '-')".  If you have a 2 x n matrix you would do "plot(points(1,:), points(2,:), '-')".

Comment: Thanks Jim, I was a bit confused, I really appreciate your help